# Plotting values normalised

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to visualise the percentage on the y-axis instead of values:

```
Date             Label
2020-12-01         1
2020-12-01         1
2020-12-01         1
2020-12-01         1
2020-12-03         1
2020-12-03         1
2020-12-04         1
2020-12-05         1
```

in order to have normalised values. Could you please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `normalize=True` to `value_counts` and plot it:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Date'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]